# What is a “prix de revient”?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, économie

How does a "prix de revient" differ from the ordinary price of an item?

P.S. I find your criteria unnecessarily picky.

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? What did you find? Why doesn't it suit your needs? Wikipedia tells you: [prix de revient =  coût de revient](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co%C3%BBt_de_revient), and tells you that in English it is [Cost of goods sold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_goods_sold).

Comment: If you want to understand the "unnecessarily picky criteria" of calculating a *prix de revient* you can consult a technical dedicated site like this one [Qu'est-ce que le coût de revient ?](https://www.l-expert-comptable.com/a/37383-qu-est-ce-que-le-cout-de-revient.html) but French Language is not the  place to ask your question. I don't what Stackexchange site would answer that. Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange? Quantitative Finance?

Answer (score 1):

It's the sum of all the costs that were needed to produce the item :

- Buying costs
- Production costs
- Distribution costs
- Administrative costs

In English, it's translated as "Cost of goods sold".

You have the same differenciation between both costs in English, as the "regular" cost would usually only cover the production/buying cost.